# Solaris 10: IPMP setup with zone and defrouter

Tags: solaris, bonding, zones

I'm a bit desesparated by some kind of "bugs" we recently faced. We are using Solaris 10 on SPARC platform (T4-4) to run zones. Obviously, we do IPMP for safety.

Some of those zones are legacy, so they are (unfortunately) using different network subnets. Thus, the global zones are connected in a lot of subnet but still have one default gateway. Now, some of these zones requires a different default gw so we used the defrouter option in zonecfg.

This is leading to unwanted behavior in the global zone: some time the traffic of the global zone goes through the regular gateway, sometimes it goes through the more specific one. Of course, we expect the global zone to ONLY use the original gateway and not the one that has been setup for the zone.

Anyway idea on how to solve this? If you have experience with that kind of setup, feedback are more than welcome :)

Cheers,

```
Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------
default              172.27.24.1          UG        1    1999373
default              192.168.17.1         UG        1     478064 igb8008
172.27.24.0          172.27.24.26         U         1      14941 igb3
172.28.0.0           172.28.1.18          U         1         55 igb588004
172.28.96.0          172.28.96.68         U         1         96 igb0
192.168.17.0         192.168.17.32        U         1       3291 igb8008
192.168.120.0        192.168.121.80       U         1       4808 igb641008
224.0.0.0            172.28.96.68         U         1          0 igb0
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        8    3685947 lo0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared IP and you have set a defrouter, then if the traffic goes via another route when no route has been defined its a bug, if you are at the latest patch bundle raise a call with Oracle.

If you could give some examples of the problems, and output of the following, it would be helpful.

```
netstat -rnv

ifconfig -a

zonecfg -z <zone> info

uname -a
```

Comment: We are using shared IP but the problem comes with the global zone, not the one that uses the defrouter option. Regarding the patch level, we first want to know if this is solved at some patch level ... we don't want to keep applying patches and reboot production servers without improvements.

Comment: The netstat output: http://pastebin.com/index/VJE6Xsrk

Comment: SunOS seville 5.10 Generic_147440-25 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: And an example of the problem?

Comment: Well, the problem is like when we have connections directly to the global zone, from time to time we have network issues because the traffic is routed to the wrong default gateway and the traffic is trashed then...